# Cannot run Python inside subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

At the end of a python script, I'm trying to run a subprocess:

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', '/var/lib/classifier/classify.py'], stderr=open('/var/log/scrapyd/dailyalerts/classifier_logfile.log', 'a'))
```

Unfortunately it's not working... The classifier_logfile.log contains the following error:

```
File "/var/lib/classifier/classify.py", line 2, in <module>
from classifier import Classifier

File "/var/lib/classifier/classifier.py", line 4, in <module>
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
ImportError: No module named sklearn.feature_extraction.text
```

The strange part is, if I run "python /var/lib/classifier/classify.py" from the terminal itself, it's just working. So because of the subprocess.Popen it's not able to import the libraries, but I don't know why.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: This is path problem, most probabily

Comment: You can try running it with the arguments as string: `subprocess.Popen('python /var/lib/classifier/classify.py', shell=True, stderr=open('/var/log/scrapyd/dailyalerts/classifier_logfile.log', 'a'))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set cwd argument in Popen function to a directory you run the command from.

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', '/var/lib/classifier/classify.py'],
    stderr=open('/var/log/scrapyd/dailyalerts/classifier_logfile.log', 'a'), 
    cwd='<your dir>')
```

Comment: messing with cwd is more often than not a bad idea.

Comment: Not working unfortunately. I'm now trying to add the classifier as middleware to scrapy